# FullCalendar Js Select Function allDay

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have a `select` function defined as follows:

```
    select: function(start,end, callback){
        var allDay = !start.hasTime();
        alert(allDay);
```

When you select a date on the calendar page, the `allDay` parameter is set to true. However, I do not want this. Is there a way to make `allDay` be set to false on `select`?

I have defined all the parameters like so:

```
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true,
        allDay:false, // I really thought this would work...but it doesn't
        ...
```

But it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

EDIT:

I have also tried setting the `allDay` in the event:

```
                start = start.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                end = end.format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                start = start + "T" + startTime;
                end = end + "T" + endTime;

                var event={title: name, start: start, end:end, description: description, allDayDefault: false};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value to `allDay` on the **event object** with `allDayDefault: false`. By default, is undefined:

```
allDayDefault: false
```

More info:
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/allDayDefault/

Comment: You need to write it on the event object, I guess you are setting this on the initialize method.

Comment: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, false); // This is what I have, so you are saying I should so something like this: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'renderEvent', event, false, allDay:false);

Comment: no, I think that doesn't works. I think your first try is good, but i don't know why it doesn't works.

Comment: It's because when I `select` a date, it automatically gives me an `end` date that has `allDay` set to true

Comment: So I invite you to provide us a working example. Not need to be the complete code, I said, avoid to post the complete code. Only the minimal code to reproduce the issue and share with us. You can use stacksnippets or external services like jsfiddle.net. See more: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask || http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve